# RESTful file upload fails with large files

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

Greenhouse's harvest API requires that I include the base64 encoded content in my post request to attach a file to a user. I put together this POST request in python, which works for files of size 70kb.

```
r = requests.post('https://harvest.greenhouse.io/v1/candidates/' + candidate_id + '/attachments', auth=(API_KEY, ''), data = json.dumps({
                    'content': base64.b64encode(file_string),                    
                    'filename': filename,
                    'type': "resume",
                    'content_type': "image/png"
                    }), headers={'On-Behalf-Of': str(recruiter_id)})
```

However, when I upload a file of size 1MB+, I get a 500 error with no error message. I asked greenhouse support whether it was possible to upload files of size 1MB+, and they were able to successfully attach the file. Is there any major syntax error that I should be aware of when making this request, then?

One thing I noticed was that my internet speed was extremely slow (2MB up, down). Could this be a possible reason why large files aren't able to be sent?

Comment: 500 error has nothing to do with the client. Their API faces issues probably. 
http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: Either use the `json` argument for your data, or add this `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in `headers`

Comment: t.m.adam - thanks, i think that fixed it. do you know why that solution worked? (edit: my internet is relatively fast again now, maybe that's also a solution?)